# Josephson junction

Tags: condensed-matter

I am unable to related the concept of flux quantization with the Josephson junction. In Kittel's book of solid state I have read that the *The phenomena of Josephson junction follows the phenomena of flux quantization*. Help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I don't have Kittel's book and the answer below follows my interpretation of the context of your question.*

The second Josephson equation is

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{2e}{\hbar}v = \frac{2\pi}{\Phi_0}v$$

where $v$ is the voltage across the junction, $\varphi$ is the phase of the Josephson junction and $\Phi_0 = h/(2e)$ is the flux quantum. Integrating the above equation yields

$$\varphi(t) = \frac{2\pi}{\Phi_0}\int_0^t v(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau + \varphi(0) = 2\pi\color{red}{\frac{\lambda(t)}{\Phi_0}} + \varphi(0)\tag{1}$$

where the quantity

$$\lambda(t) = \int_0^t v(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$$

is the [*flux linkage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_linkage) (in a solenoid this quantity actually equals the total magnetic flux linked by the solenoid winding).

Therefore, from (1), the phase $\varphi$ of the Josephson junction "counts" the number of flux quanta $\lambda(t)/\Phi_0$ (in red in (1)) "crossing" the junction at time $t$.

Comment: So quantization of fluxoids  is only related to AC Josephson effect.